# I have an array which has 2 object, In each object i have a array of object. I want to get only those data's which matches the attributes

Tags: javascript

[Object Object]

each object contains an array which will contain multiple objects.

The object will contain different parameters for eg connection Type .. so based on specific connection type I want to get all the values that satisfy the connection Type.

const data: [object, object] = [{connectionRequired:[{connectionType: water},{connectionType: petrol}]},
  {connectionRequired: [{connectionType: petrol},{"connectionType":water}]}]

Here I want same [object object] which will contain connection type as water excluding any other connection Type

I want something like this

const data: [object, object] = [{"connectionRequired": [{"connectionType": "water"}]},
  {"connectionRequired": [{"connectionType": "water"}]}]

Comment: There seem to be no code, whatsoever in your post.

Comment: Hey Chetan welcome to Stackoverflow. If you could add a snippet of your code to enable us help you debug would be quite awesome.

Comment: current code and required code added

Answer (score 0):

Your question needs to have examples of the data you're working with, and the code you've tried, in order to be properly answerable. But here's something that might help get things started:

```js
interface IConnectionData {
  connectionRequired: { connectionType: string }[];
}

const dataIn: [IConnectionData, IConnectionData] = [
  { connectionRequired: [{ connectionType: 'water' }, { connectionType: 'petrol' }] },
  { connectionRequired: [{ connectionType: 'petrol' }, { "connectionType": 'water' }] }
];

const dataOut = dataIn
  .map(
    x => ({
      ...x,
      connectionRequired: x
        .connectionRequired
        .filter(c => c.connectionType === 'water')
    }),
) as [IConnectionData, IConnectionData];
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=20&ssc=22&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIGED2IQQWYbAETjDmQG8AoZZBbXfQkAJQgEcBXYKCAEwBclOgzwFsAFQCeABwhCAzmCigA5sgC+AbQC6AbioaqVeiCXI+pOKhBCtGUU2JWANGiw4xzEmR3IAvMhaNMKmjOKsHNy8gkEUIp5OINJyQgDkAO6k0GmabvFhXpKy8shpcsqYADa5Gn4aLiEFjhFsXDz8ds2JESml5RCVNXnCAESFSX2j6VmQULX1VPrGpuaWZADynGABFlY2IQB0ALZwMgAUIbQAHgEAfMjn1LQvyIfv142vtBOtUR2xa5Xb6HX7MNrRfjA16HGDAKpzc4Ie50UEtZh9AL+QKZbLzACUwI0+Ma+OQcAUQQcPW8rnc6OcvgMJmwCmqEEOVUwqnO6zgWzA+L0QA)

Comment: @ChetanRaoKC This should now work for you - please upvote and accept the answer if you're happy with it